# Photoshop Problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign

How do you nudge an image by counting as one whole without photoshop auto-creating copies of the same layer?  I'm using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key</kbd> to nudge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a basic question about the use of a software, the answer to which can be easily found by consulting said software's help files.

Comment: Try using alt/opt alone with the arrow key, or control alone with the arrow key. There might be a vagary (great word) of your individual set-up as it is with my personal situation, too.

Answer (score 1):

Holding down Alt will create duplicate layers. Don't do that.

Instead, set the zoom to 100%.  Select the Move tool, and nudge with the arrow keys only. Increments will be 1px.

If you zoom out to 50%, the increments will be 2px. 25% zoom will result in 4px increments.

If you hold down Shift while you nudge, the increments will be 10px.

Comment: It's solved thank you. Also, It does not duplicate layers while hold Alt(Options). Only notice it duplicated while holding (Control Key).